# How to chage color of confirm button in image picker in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using image picker for selecting videos form gallery. When I select a video, then a page opens for playing the video and confirming the selection. On that, the color of confirm button is green. I want to change that.

Is there any way to change it or redesign it?

Take a look at this ss for example:

[image]

That confirm button in right hand corner is what i need to change (At least color and text).
I don't want to implement image picking from scratch just for this, so is there any way top change this property? I am using `image_picker` package for the same.

Code is simply:

```
List<Media>? res = await ImagesPicker.pick(
      count: 1,
      pickType: PickType.video,

    );
```

Comment: Are you using an external package for the video picker? Can you add that as well?

Comment: Yes, I am using image_picker

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for changing the color in image_picker